# TFS & VSTS notification

Tags: tfs, active-directory, azure-devops

does anyone know where to stop any notification from TFS & VSTS platform? we are migrate from TFS <> VSTS and the people getting notification on each sync that happened, I'm thinking maybe the notification came from the active directory ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you solve this issue after turning off notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `https://[account].visualstudio.com/_notifications` to turn off notifications.

[Manage your notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/notifications/manage-personal-notifications)

On the other hand, you can manage team’s notification: `https://[account].visualstudio.com/[team project]/_admin/_notifications`